# Parse Server relation.add() not working

Tags: parse-platform, addition, parse-server, relation

**Issue Description**

If I create a relation and use the relation.add() method on it nothing happens.

**Steps to reproduce**

```
let Booking = Parse.Object.extend("Booking")
let bookingQuery = new Parse.Query(Booking)
bookingQuery.get(newBookingObject.id, {
success: booking => {

    console.log("invites", invites)
    // prints array of existing ParseObjects from another class

    let relation = booking.relation("invites")
    console.log(relation) 
    // prints new relation with key "invites" and parent "Booking"

    relation.add(invites)
    console.log(relation)
    // prints exactly the same relation object as before - nothing changed

    booking.save().then(res => console.log(res))
    // an empty relation is added
},
error: error => console.log("error", error)
// no errors
})
```

**Expected Results**

relation.add(arrayOfParseObjects) should add objects to relation

**Actual Outcome**

Nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

insted of

```
    relation.add(invites)
```

please try the following

```
    for (var i =0; i<invites.length;i++){
    relation.add(invites[i])
    }
```

Regards